# How to set name of json file populated with data from mysql database with Node.js?

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I'm new in Node.js. Trying to populate json file with data from database. And I need help for setting the name of this json file.   Here is the code:

```
            var http = require('http');

            http.createServer(function(req, res) {
                console.log('Receving request...');

                var callback = function(err, result) {
                    res.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type' : 'x-application/json'
                    });
                    console.log('json:', result);
                    res.end(result);    
                };

            connectToDb(callback, queryData);}  
            ).listen(9999);

            function connecToDb(callback, queryData){
            var mysql = require('mysql');
                var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                    host : 'localhost',
                    user : 'xxxx',
                    password : 'xxxx',
                    database : 'xxxx',
                    port: 3306
                });

                connection.connect();
                var json = '';
                var data = queryData + '%';
                var query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE POSTCODE LIKE "' + data + '"';
                connection.query(query, function(err, results, fields) {
                    if (err)
                        return callback(err, null);

                    console.log('The query-result is: ', results);

                    // wrap result-set as json
                    json = JSON.stringify(results);

                    /***************
                    * Correction 2: Nest the callback correctly!
                    ***************/
                    connection.end();
                    console.log('JSON-result:', json);
                    callback(null, json);
                });
            }
```

I get file named as "download", what should I use to name it "myJson.json"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a content-disposition header with the value "attachment; filename=" + filename

where filename is whatver you want the filename to be.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the callback code like this, and it works: var callback = function(err, result) {
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=myJson.json');
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type' : 'x-application/json'
        });
        console.log('json:', result);
        res.end(result); 
    };